# how to download utf-8 encoded content with cyrillic

Tags: python, http, encoding

Please show me the way to get correct utf-8 content with cyrillic.

I use next code snippet:

```
from http.client import HTTPSConnection

conn = HTTPSConnection('lifehacker.ru')
conn.request('GET', '/')
resp = conn.getresponse()
st = resp.read()
content = ''.join(map(chr, st))
conn.close()
print(content)
```

As result I get content with some like:

```
<title>ÐÐ°Ð¹ÑÑÐ°ÐºÐµÑ - ÑÐ¾Ð²ÐµÑÑ Ð¸
```

How to get correct cyrillic symbols?

Comment: Are you confined to using http.client? If not, use Requests library which uses the server's content-type field to return a Unicode string in `response.text`

Comment: have you try putting the line `# -*- coding: utf8 -*-` at the begining of the script, what python are you using?

Comment: @JorgeRodriguezMolinuevo that has nothing to do with the encoding of data recieved outside of the script.

Answer (score 1):

you should decode the content like that

```
st = resp.read().decode("utf-8")
```

easier way is to use requests somehow they decode the content automatically

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://lifehacker.ru')

print(response.text)
```

Comment: I do not know who and why marked the answer as negative... Maybe he will explain why your answer is wrong. But for me it works fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'. I have Python 3.6 in windows. Will study the way to install the Request module. I am python newby. Thanks.

Comment: Because there is no need to use the convoluted `join`, `map`, `encode`, `decode`. You just need to `st.decode`

Comment: @KostadinSlavov it was you who proposed to `.encode('latin1')` which is unecesary and dangerous.

Comment: Thank you, mate appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you must use HTTPSConnection, you need to decode the response with the appropriate encoding:

```
content = st.decode('utf-8')
```

(In Python 3, `resp.read()` returns a byte object ready for decoding with the appropriate encoding)

**However, do not hardcode the encoding, i.e. UTF-8. Use the `Content-type` field to work out the correct encoding or use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library instead, which does this for you.**